# Быстрый поиск чисел из n цифр вида 74444744444

Tags: python, алгоритм, поиск

Здравствуйте, для решения одной задачи нужно быстро находить все числа, стостоящие из `n` цифр, каждая цифра - это либо `4` , либо `7`. И число должно без остатка делиться на `4` и на `7`.

Например `74444744444` - один из примеров для `11` цифр. Всё, что смогла выдовить моя головушка за пару часов - это данный код . Работает медленно уже для `n > 10`, прошу помочь усовершенствовать его или поменять, если я много не знаю )

```
n = int(input())
s2 = int(("7"+ "4"*(n-3) + "44")
s22 = int("7" * n)
s1 = int("4"*n) 
s11 = int("4" + "7"*(n-1))

while (s1 - 644)%700 !=0:
    s1 += 1

while (s2 - 644)%700 !=0:

    s2 += 1
a1 = [i for i in range(s1,s11 + 1,700) if str(i).replace("4","").replace("7","") == ""]
a2 = [i for i in range(s2,s22 + 1,700) if str(i).replace("4","").replace("7","") == ""]
a = a1 + a2
```

Comment: Всем большое спасибо . Очень помогли разобраться !

Comment: Отметьте тогда наиболее понравившийся как ответ (слева галочка)

Comment: Спасибо за отличную задачу!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def check(number, power):
    # переводим в двоичный вид и заменяем 0 на 4, 1 на 7
    array = [(7 if (number >> i & 0x1) else 4) for i in range(power)]
    total = 0
    base = 1
    # собираем назад и получаем число
    for value in array:
        total += value * base
        base *= 10
    # НОК чисел 4 и 7 = 28
    if total % 28 == 0:
        print(total)
```

Можно убрать лишние переменные:

```
def check(number, power):
    total = sum([(7 if (number >> i & 0x1) else 4) * 10 ** i for i in range(power)])
    if total % 28 < 1:
        print(total)


n = 11
# пробегаем циклом по всем возможным значениям:
for num in range(2 ** n):
    check(num, n)
```

Результат (0,2 секунды):

```
44444444744
44444774444
44447447744
44447777444
44474447444
44474474744
44474747744
44477477744
44477744444
44744444444
44744744744
44747447444
44747474744
44747747744
44774474444
44774747444
44774774744
44777477444
44777777744
47444477444
47444777744
47447444744
47447774444
47474444444
47474744744
47477447444
47477474744
47477747744
47744447744
47744777444
47747444444
47747744744
47774477744
47774744444
47777474444
47777747444
47777774744
74444477744
74444744444
74447474444
74447747444
74447774744
74474444744
74474774444
74477447744
74477777444
74744477444
74744777744
74747444744
74747774444
74774444444
74774744744
74777447444
74777474744
74777747744
77444447444
77444474744
77444747744
77447477744
77447744444
77474477444
77474777744
77477444744
77477774444
77744474444
77744747444
77744774744
77747477444
77747777744
77774447744
77774777444
77777444444
77777744744
[Finished in 0.2s]
```

> А если усложнить задачу и вывести ВСЕ числа, состоящие из n, (n-1),
>   (n-2),... цифр, делящиеся на 28? – `Viktor Tomilov`

```
for n in range(1, 12):
    for num in range(2 ** n):
        check(num, n)
```

Comment: А если усложнить задачу и вывести ВСЕ числа, состоящие из n, (n-1), (n-2),...1 цифр, делящиеся на 28?

Comment: @ViktorTomilov обновил ответ, просто добавить лишний цикл, на время выполнения особо не повлияет

Answer (score 4):

Для какого именно N?

Я бы рекомендовал заметить, что на 4 делятся только числа, заканчивающиеся на 44, что уже уменьшает количество работы - надо генерировать только N-2-значные числа (уже в 4 раза меньше), проверять делимость на 4 не нужно.

Далее, чтобы не делить числа, лучше использовать генерацию бинарного кода Грея (см. алгоритм G на стр. 334 тома 4А у Кнута), у которого изменяется единственная цифра при переходе к следующему числу - тогда остаток от деления вычисляется простым суммированием, без делений вовсе.

Для N до 18 включительно (т.е. 64-битных чисел) работает ну очень быстро. Дальше - нужно переписывать для другого представления чисел, что, в общем-то, именно в данном варианте алгоритма - через коды Грея - не так и сложно...

Я, увы, python не знаю, но на С++ - вот:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

void generate(int N)
{
    const int maxi = 18;  // Ограничены long long
    if (N < 4 || N > maxi) { cout << "No solutions"; return; }

    int rems[maxi];  // Массив остатков от 3, 30, 300 и т.д.
    unsigned long long ten = 1;
    for(int i = 0; i < maxi; ++i)
    {
        rems[i] = (ten*3ll)%7ll;
        ten *= 10ll;
    }

    char s[maxi+1] = { 0 };
    for(int i = 0; i < maxi; ++i) s[i] = '4';

    unsigned long long rem = atoll(s+maxi-N)%7;

    for(bool a = false;;)
    {
        if (rem == 0)
            cout << (s+maxi-N) << endl;
        int j = 0;
        if (!(a = !a))
        {
            for(++j;s[maxi-2-j] == '4';++j);
            if (j == N-2) break;
        }

        s[maxi-3-j] = (s[maxi-3-j] == '4') ? '7' : '4';
        int sign = (s[maxi-3-j] == '4') ? -1 : 1;
        rem = (rem + 7 + sign*rems[j+2])%7;
    }
}



int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    generate(18);
}
```

Для 15 - тут: https://ideone.com/TIrOTD - судя по их точности, менее 0.01 секунды :)

Для произвольного количества (только уже подольше... у меня для 25 цифр считало уже около 3 секунд):

```
void generate(int N)
{
    const int maxi = 100;  // За глаза хватит :)
    if (N < 4 || N > maxi) { cout << "No solutions"; return; }

    int rems[maxi];  // Массив остатков от 3, 30, 300 и т.д.
    rems[0] = 3;
    for(int i = 1; i < maxi; ++i)
    {
        rems[i] = (rems[i-1]*10)%7;
    }

    char s[maxi+1] = { 0 };
    for(int i = 0; i < maxi; ++i) s[i] = '4';

    int rem = 4;
    for(int i = 1; i < N; ++i)
        rem = (rem*10+4)%7;

    for(bool a = false;;)
    {
        if (rem == 0)
            cout << (s+maxi-N) << endl;
        int j = 0;
        if (!(a = !a))
        {
            for(++j;s[maxi-2-j] == '4';++j);
            if (j == N-2) break;
        }

        s[maxi-3-j] = (s[maxi-3-j] == '4') ? '7' : '4';
        int sign = (s[maxi-3-j] == '4') ? -1 : 1;
        rem = (rem + 7 + sign*rems[j+2])%7;
    }
}
```

Конечно, интересно бы как-то воспользоваться еще каким-то признаком делимости на 7, но что-то это у меня не получается... С другой стороны, при 25 цифрах уже получается почти 1200 тысяч вариантов, так что вряд ли имеет смысл создавать что-то более эффективное?

Comment: Я, кстати, так завис на попытке плясать от ".....44" и применения признака делимости на 7, что даже не стал публиковать стандартный ответ - его уже (почти точно такой же) опубликовали. Но идея использовать признак делимости пока не умерла :)

Comment: Забавно, заминусовали - что не так? На phyton кто-то перевести не в состоянии? :) так я идеологически все изложил, источники указал.

Comment: `generate` отличный.

Answer (score 3):

```
from itertools import product

def numbers(n):
    raw = (int(''.join(i)) for i in product('47', repeat=n))
    for i in raw:
        if i%4==0 and i%7==0:
            yield i

for i in numbers(11):
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Научимся безошибочно находить нужные числа.

Число делится на четыре и на семь тогда и только тогда когда оно делится на `28`. Научимся быстро считать остаток от деления числа на `28` на примере числа `4744477447`.

Первая таблица. Первый столбец - номер цифры в числе (0 - младший разряд). Второй столбец в пояснениях не нуждается. Замечу только что его можно вычислить последовательно: `10 = 10 * 1 % 28`, `16 = 10 * 10 % 28`, ..., `r(i) = 10 * r(i-1) % 28`, ... Третий столбец - цифры числа `4744477447`. Четвёртый столбец - произведение цифр на соответствующие остатки для степеней десяти. Внизу таблицы сумма остатков и её остаток.

> ```
> i    10^i % 28    d_i    d_i * 10^i % 28
>       
> 0        1    *    7      =      7      
> 1       10    *    4      =     40
> 2       16    *    4      =     64
> 3       20    *    7      =    140
> 4        4    *    7      =     28
> 5       12    *    4      =     48
> 6        8    *    4      =     32
> 7       24    *    4      =     96
> 8       16    *    7      =    112
> 9       20    *    4      =     80
>                                ---
>                                647        % 28 = 3
>                         4744477447        % 28 = 3
> ```

Во второй таблице перечислены все пятизначные числа из четвёрок и единиц. Таблица сгруппирована по модулю `28`:

> ```
>  i          n        n % 28  |     i          n        n % 28
>                              |
>  0    44744            0     |    14    47474, 74774    14
>  1    77447           27     |    15    44477           13
>  2    77474           26     |    16    47444, 74744    12
>  3    74477           25     |    17    44447           11
>  4    77444           24     |    18    44474           10
>  5    74447           23     |    19    47777            9
>  6    74474           22     |    20    44444            8
>  7    77777           21     |    21    47747            7
>  8    74444           20     |    22    47774            6
>  9    77747           19     |    23    44777            5
> 10    77774           18     |    24    47744            4
> 11    47477, 74777    17     |    25    44747            3
> 12    77744           16     |    26    44774            2
> 13    47447, 74747    15     |    27    77477            1
> ```

Если мы хотим сделать десятизначное число будем перебирать все комбинации старших цифр. Вместо пяти младших цифр будут нули. Пусть очередная комбинация `7744700000`. Сосчитаем её остаток по модулю `28`. Для этого нам подойдёт первая таблица. Остаток вычисляется без деления длинных чисел:

> ```
> d_i                  7   7   4   4   7   0   0   0   0   0
>       10^i % 28     20  16  24   8  12
> d_i * 10^i % 28    140 112  96  32  84
>                    ---------------------------------------
>                            464
> ```

`464 % 28 = 16`. Из второй таблицы берём хвосты из шестнадцатой строки: `47444` и `74744`. У обоих остаток `12`. Если сложить старшие цифры и хвосты получатся числа с остатком ноль: `7744747444` и `7744774744`.

Любые комбинации старших цифр можно продолжить так чтобы получилось число которое делится на `28` без остатка. Так что будем рекурсивно перебирать старшие цифры. В процессе рекурсии поддерживать сумму остатков не сложно. Для комбинации старших цифр с известным остатком хвосты добавляются из таблицы пятизначных хвостов. Это значит что наш перебор никогда не делает возвраты и тратит на каждую цифру ответа константное время. Следовательно, это оптимальный по времени перебор.

Обратите внимание, что длинных умножений и делений в программе нет. Так как не нужна длинная арифметика, программу легко портировать на `C++`. Производительность будет ограничена только печатью.

```
import itertools


def numbers(n):
    for p in itertools.product('47', repeat=n):
        s = ''.join(p)
        yield int(s) % 28, s


def tails(n):
    d = tuple([] for _ in range(28))
    for r, s in numbers(n):
        k = (28 - r) % 28
        d[k].append(s)
    return d


def base():
    n = 1
    while True:
        t = tails(n)
        if all(t):
            return n, t
        n += 1


def rems28(n):
    rem = 1
    for _ in range(n):
        yield rem
        rem = 10 * rem % 28


def print_fast(n, n_min, tails):
    tails = tuple(tuple(t + '\n' for t in lst) for lst in tails)
    rems = tuple(rems28(n))

    term_rems = tuple(3 * r % 28 for r in rems[n_min:])[::-1]
    number = ['4'] * len(term_rems)
    m = len(number)

    def recursive_print(i, rem):
        if i == m:
            head = ''.join(number)
            for t in tails[rem % 28]:
                print(head, end=t)
        else:
            recursive_print(i + 1, rem)
            number[i] = '7'
            recursive_print(i + 1, rem + term_rems[i])
            number[i] = '4'

    base_rem = 4 * sum(rems[n_min:]) % 28
    recursive_print(0, base_rem)


def print_numbers(n):
    assert n > 0
    n_min, tails = base()
    if n < n_min:
        for r, s in numbers(n):
            if r == 0:
                print(s)
    else:
        print_fast(n, n_min, tails)


print_numbers(int(input()))
```

> ```
> $ echo 8 | python fast.py
> 44474444
> 44747444
> 44774744
> 47477444
> 47777744
> 74447744
> 74777444
> 77444444
> 77744744
>
> $ time echo 22 | python fast.py | wc -l
> 149796
>
> real  0m0.173s
> user  0m0.168s
> sys   0m0.008s
>
> $ time echo 27 | python fast.py | wc -l
> 4793490
>
> real  0m4.721s
> user  0m4.748s
> sys   0m0.124s
> ```